# Update recyclerview on button click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have another problem or bug in my Android app. Sorry I am new to Android development, but it is my passion and I will persevere.

Anyways, my code is crashing in a method call in my CustomAdapter class.

This is my CustomAdapter class where it is crashing:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<UserInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
float ratings;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<UserInfo> arrayList){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.userslayout, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder customViewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return customViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final UserInfo userInfo = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.username.setText(userInfo.getMusicName());
    holder.forename.setText(userInfo.getMusicCategory());
    holder.surname.setText(userInfo.getFileType());
    // THE APP CRASHES WHEN I CLICK THIS BUTTON. THINGS UPDATE IN THE 
    // DATABASE - BUT THE RECYCLERVIEW CRASHES AND THE APP CRASHES
    holder.buttonRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String pressed = Integer.toString(userInfo.getPressedName());
            UserListRecycler userListRecycler = new UserListRecycler();
            UserListRecycler.UserPressedAsync userPressedAsync = userListRecycler.new UserPressedAsync();
            userPressedAsync.execute(username, pressed);
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is my `UserListRecycler` class - the main class, and the inner class `UserPressedAsync`

```
public class UserListRecycler extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static UserAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<UserInfo> list;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlistGUI, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reUsers);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        // Instantiate new adapter here
        adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        // Sets the adapter here
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        populateRecyclerList();
    }


    public void populateList(){
        PopulateUsers userList = new PopulateUsers(list, adapter, recyclerView);
        userList.execute();
    }

    public class UserPressedAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // REST STUFF HAPPENS HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String postData) {
        // CRASHES HERE!!!
        populateRecyclerList();
    }
}
}
```

This is my `PopulateUsers` class - where details from my server are retrieve via `REST`

```
public class PopulateUsers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    static ArrayList<UserInfo> list;
    UserAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

public PopulateUsers(ArrayList<UserInfo> list, UserAdapter adapter, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>(); 
    this.adapter = new UserAdapter();
    this.list = list;
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // `REST` Activity happens here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    try {
        list.clear();  
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            String forename = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("forename");
            String surname = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("surname");
            String nationality = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nationality");
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(forename, surname, nationality);
            list.add(userInfo);
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Basically, when the button is clicked things are updated in the `backend`, i.e. `phpmyadmin` `mysql` server - but the app does not reload with the updated list as it crashes. It is something to do with the `populateList()` method in my `UserListRecycler` class, it points the error at the `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` in the `PopulateUsers` class - precisely in `onPostExecute()`, as a `NullPointerException`, but it works fine when the `UserListRecycler` class is first instantiated and loaded. So why does it crash, when I call the `populateList()` method?

This is my stack trace:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at lukasz.usersapp.PopulateUsers.onPostExecute(PopulateUsers.java:67)
            at lukasz.usersapp.PopulateUsers.onPostExecute(PopulateUsers.java:27)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It would really mean a lot, in fact some sleep for myself if someone could help me resolve this problem. It is a horrible bug!

Answer (score 3):

The error basically comes from the fact that you are accessing your recyclerview while its adapter is not yet instantiated. That is because you are displaying the recyclerview in the main thread while setting it up in background. In your case the two threads are not sync, so while you are clicking the button, the recyclerview is not yet properly set up, thus giving you a null pointer exception.

I suggest that you find a work around on getting the data to display, then setup your recyclerview before displaying it.

It is really not a good idea to have a web call using asynctask, you usually have to use libraries like retrofit, gson, rxandroid, etc., but since you are just starting, you have to make do with asynctask.

I suggest you do your `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)` in your main thread like in your `onCreate`, since you don't have the data required to display your recyclerview, you have to either set it up with dummy data first or, more preferably, don't display it yet, display a progress bar first to tell the user that it is not yet done loading.

If you do what I suggested, you don't have to call `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)` in your asynctask, you just have to notify it that you have changes, which is of course your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: So how do I fix this horrible bug, please? I literally can't sleep and I keep banging my head on the wall

Comment: Is there a way you can maybe fix my code? Surely, it is moving a line here and there

Comment: where does your json comes from? From api?

Comment: the `json` stuff is good. My database updates and all, but the app crashes because of this bloody `recyclerview`!!!!!!

Comment: please, could you tell me what line to put in my code or class - it would mean a lot

Comment: Man this is really hard, is there anything I can change in my current code to make it work

Comment: Im getting `No adapter attached; skipping layout` because I am not calling `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)` in the `asynctask` class

Comment: Please help me, my code works but it just crashes when I try and reload the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

`recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

You are calling that twice. Why not just leave it in the `onCreateView` with and remove it from the `postExecute`? Just leave the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` there in the postExecute and remove it from onCreateView. Does it make a difference?

I am using the library **Volley** for those tasks and it's fairly easy to use. Looks neater than `ASyncTask` as well. Maybe you could give it a try.

Have a look at that page: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

If you clone the `Volley library` (a folder gets downloaded), Import it into Android Studio via `New>Import MODULE>path to library`. Then you need to put `compile project(':volley')` into your app's `Build gradle` under dependencies - so it looks something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':volley')
}
```

This is how my method to download `JSON` from my php service looks like:

```
  public void downloadEvents(String urlService) {


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()); //getActivity because I'm calling it from a fragment, if called in Activity, use 'this'
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, urlService, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    try {


                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject eventJson = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String title = eventJson.getString("EventTitle");
                            String body = eventJson.getString("EventBody");
                            double price = Double.parseDouble(eventJson.getString("EventPrice"));
                            String date = eventJson.getString("EventDate");
                            String time = eventJson.getString("EventTime");
                            String place = eventJson.getString("EventPlace");
                            String organ = eventJson.getString("Organization");

                            Event event = new Event(title, body, price, date, time, durationStr, place, organ);
                            theEvents.add(event);
                            rAdapter.notifyItemInserted(i);
                        }


                        if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY ERROR", "" + error);

                }
            }
            );

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest); //important to add that otherwise the download wont be initiated.
}
```

You can see how I handle my JSON and where I could use things like `swipeRefreshLayout`.
Note that this is still done `asynchronously`.

The important thing is to go and check your `JSON responses` and see if the response starts with an object or an array. Then adjust the `Volley` code accordingly. It's basically changing most `Array` keywords in the code to `Object` (if you are receiving a JSON object holding your data). Example:

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, urlService, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
```

becomes

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest 
            (Request.Method.GET, urlService, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

....

In my onCreate, before using `downloadEvents("http//example.com/service.php");`
I have done all the `RecyclerView` and adapter code:

```
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    theEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    rAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(theEvents, recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
```

The download method just notifies the adapter.

Comment: How do I use volley, is there any way I can convert my code to volley?

Comment: I gave you an almost complete Volley tutorial. I hope it is straightforward and it helps you. The way I did it (for now) this method is where I'm setting the data so my list and adapter are in the same class(fragment). That's why I just add to the list and notify my adapter like that.

Comment: Thanks, but what is `Event event = new Event(title, body, price, date, time, durationStr, place, organ);`? Also, if I were to put the volley code in a separate class, would it work?

Comment: I think it's supposed to work but when I tried it I had all kinds of problems and it didn't work so I put it in the same class. Oh sorry, event is just my own class for my type of data. It's exactly the same as your userInfo class. You do the same thing as me - you create a userInfo object and add it to the list. You can see that what you do in the onPostExecute corresponds to the onResponse method in Volley, just get the json data into the variables and create your userInfo object there.

Comment: Hi, I tried you approach and it still crashes with a `null pointer exception` on `RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());`

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I'd need to see how you implemented Volley, can you update your question with the new code please?

Comment: Hi, actually I found out why I may be having this problem. Basically, my code crashes because it is calling a method within its `outer` class. I dont know how to fix it - please see my latest question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761130/how-do-i-call-a-method-in-my-fragment-class