# How do I call an outer class method in my inner class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, inner-classes

So I was having a `bug` where my code was crashing because I am calling methods in my `outer` class in `onPostExecute`.

So this is my simple class:

```
public class UsersList extends Fragment{
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }

    public void callMe(){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "I work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public class UserRecommend extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
                // The line below crashes with NullPointerException
                UsersList.this.callMe();
            }
        }
}
```

So `UserRecommend` is an inner class in `UsersList`, and so I am calling the `callMe()` method and it is crashing. It is crashing for any method in my `outer` class which is `UsersList`. I know I can print `toast` directly, but I don't want to as I have a more complex method. How do I fix this, I need to call a method in the `outer` class

EDIT:
I found the main `bug` - but I don't know how to fix it. Basically, I have a custom recyclerview adapter and that `cardview` has a `recommend` button. When the user clicks the `recommend` button - it invokes a method which handles the `db` stuff and recalls a `populate` method. I feel that this is where the problem lies but here is the bit where I define the `button` action:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.recommendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UsersList usersList = new UsersList();
                UsersList.UsersRecommend usersRecommend = usersList.new UsersRecommend(usersList);
                usersRecommend.execute();
            }
        });
    }
```

That above method is in my `CustomAdapter` class and that `button` is defined in that class and not my main `UsersList` class

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:43)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
        at lukazs.usersapp.UsersList.getRView(UsersList.java:186)
        at lukazs.usersapp.UsersList.callMe(UsersList.java:161)
        at lukazs.usersapp.UsersList$UserRecommend.onPostExecute(UsersList.java:459)
        at lukazs.usersapp.UsersList$UserRecommend.onPostExecute(UsersList.java:431)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Because I am calling the `UserRecommend` class from another CustomAdapter class, I believe it is losing the activity.
It is crashing on this specific line:
`RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());`

This is my code for where I call this function:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.recommendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UsersList usersList = new UsersList();
                UsersList.UsersRecommend usersRecommend = usersList.new UsersRecommend(usersList);
                usersRecommend.execute();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need to paste your stack trace -- I think you're making assumptions about why its failing that are not true.

Comment: Agreeing with @AmirAfghani, also as there is no ambiguity you should be able to just call `callme();`

Comment: What's most likely happening is the screen is rotated or the Fragment otherwise detached from the Activity while the AsyncTask is running, so when he calls getContext() inside callMe(), it returns null, which crashes the subsequent Toast.makeText() call.

Comment: I found the bug, it is in another class - my customadapter, but I don't know how to fix it. I have added it to my OP

Comment: I had the same code for a button in my RecyclerView and it made my app crash indeed...I was trying to help but now if someone answers, he would help me too...

Comment: can you show me the error logcat.?

Comment: I have updated the OP